# How to know That if user is seeing the mobile or desktop version of my site

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

my website ( www.rrprogram.ga ) is Responsive. I maked it responsive with the help of meta tags.
Now I want to know that the user who is surfing through my site is watching mobile or desktop version of my site....

Comment: Use google analytics, for example, or any other library for web site analytics.

Comment: Assuming you need to do this on the client-side, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries